# Pushing sql statments from java to database, executeUpdate() returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql

So i am trying to store information into a database from a java application, but I am getting this error: ""AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" and I can for the life of me not find the reason. 
I jave tried changing the names of the variables and i have tried using "PreparedStatment" aswell. yet nothing has worked so far.

```
public class Db {

public static final String DRIVER ="com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oving8";
public static final String USER = "root";
public static final String PW = "";
private static Connection kobling;

private static Statement settOppStatment(){
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection tilkobling = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PW);
        return tilkobling.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not find the class in");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        }
    return null;
}
public static void skrivEnhetTilDB(Enhet enhet){
Statement st = settOppStatment();

String ID = Enhet.getId();
String Navn = Enhet.getNavn();
String sqlEnhet = null;


if (enhet != null){
    sqlEnhet = "INSERT INTO enhet VALUES('"+ ID + "','" +  Navn + "');";
};
System.out.println(sqlEnhet);

try {
    st.executeUpdate(sqlEnhet);  <---- Line 123
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("This unit is already registerd");
}
try {
    st.getConnection().close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

};

And the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at fil.Db.skrivEnhetTilDB(Db.java:123)
at main.Jframe$9.actionPerformed(Jframe.java:385)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: your `settOppStatment` method must have returned null.

Comment: `settOppStatment()` returned `null` because of some error in establishing connection and create statement.

Comment: Try to debug code and check that you enter right password, login, url and driver - its looks like You dont connect to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After may hours of work i saw that it was a spelling error.

Before:
    public static final String DRIVER ="com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";

After:

```
public static final String DRIVER ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return null if you are getting any of those exceptions. In that case since you have sysout you should see those messages in your console or log file.

You could also use debugger to check line by line what is happening.

```
private static Statement settOppStatment(){
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection tilkobling = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PW);
        return tilkobling.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not find the class in");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well, I couldnt really understand anything there, so that didnt help much.

Comment: Do you see "Can not find the class in" or "Can not connect to database" on your console or log file?

Comment: Nope, it just returns the sysout and the the stacktrace

Comment: What do you mean by returns sysout? What code is at Db.java line 123?

Comment: I marked the line in the code

st.executeUpdate(sqlEnhet);